# wordpress Admin panel is coming blank?

Tags: php, wordpress

When i moved my wordpress from one hosting to another , the admin panel is coming blank, not even showing the login screen, I tried by renaming the plugin folder and checked the white space in functions.php then also i didn't get any response.

Comment: As a first stop, check your server error logs.

Comment: did your domain change?

Comment: We have changed the server not domain

Comment: did u setup new database configuration based on the new server?

Comment: ya all databases settings are chnaged,hence the home is working fine.

Comment: update the permalink settings

Comment: Is the frontend showing correctly, or is that blank as well?

Comment: Frontend is showing correctly only wp-admin is blank

Comment: How can i update permalink my admin is not showing?

Comment: please enable the error reporting in wp-config.php file

Comment: You can not store your admin password weak , that also will be a reason for the blank admin. Also check file permissions (644 for files and 755 for folders)

Comment: I have changed my folder permissions then also didnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made search replace for the old domain variable with the new domain variable? Please try this php code.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

It will make search and replace the variable from your wordpress database. Make sure to keep the backup of database before using this.

Also make WP_DEBUG to true to check any kind of error. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works perfectly found issue in one of my plugin.Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Take wp_options table in database and change option_name (siteurl and home) to the new url

Comment: Have changed the option_name in database, my front is working correctly.